# BingAds - how to identify if a request comes from a paid Bing Ad?

Tags: bing-api

I am developing an analytics tool for sites. One of it's job is to identify traffic coming from Paid Ads from Google Adwords and BingAds.

With Adwords I had an easier job since I found that if the Referrer has the **gclid** parameter it means that it comes from Adwords. We had very accurate results with that.

But with Bingads I seem to have an issue, since it looks like requests coming from paid Bing Ads have no specific parameter that makes me realize it's a request from BingAds.

So my question is that is there a way (similar to Adwords' case) to determine if a request comes from a Bing Ad and how to do that?

Thanks ahead!
---Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bing Ads does not have a feature similar to [auto tagging in AdWords](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1752125?hl=en) which gives a one-click way to add the gclid parameter to all referrers. Instead you will need to use [dynamic text parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-campaign-management-parameters-and-automatic-keyword-insertion.aspx) in your destination URLs.